# java.lang.NullPointerException in a listview

Tags: android, json, android-listview, nullpointerexception

Since i'm new to Android i couldn't figure out why ListView isn't fetching values from the ArrayList and thus showing NullPointerException.

I am trying to view stuffs in a ListView from a json link on a TextView click using custom dialog.

Logcat:

```
02-26 05:42:22.905: E/AndroidRuntime(1441): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-26 05:42:22.905: E/AndroidRuntime(1441): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-26 05:42:22.905: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at com.example.customalertdialoglistview.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:106)
02-26 05:42:22.905: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
02-26 05:42:22.905: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
02-26 05:42:22.905: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-26 05:42:22.905: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-26 05:42:22.905: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-26 05:42:22.905: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-26 05:42:22.905: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-26 05:42:22.905: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-26 05:42:22.905: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-26 05:42:22.905: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-26 05:42:22.905: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

MainActivity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    vehino = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    // add button listener
    vehino.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // custom dialog
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
            dialog.setTitle("Select Id...");
            ThreadPolicy tp = ThreadPolicy.LAX;
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(tp);
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();


            ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> state_cons=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

            try {
                json2=JSONfunctions
                        .getJSONfromURL("http://192.168.1.63/inba/mtc/mtc_enduser/vehicle_id_pop.php");
                jsonarray = json2.getJSONArray("vehicle");

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i=0;i<jsonarray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject c=jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    HashMap<String,String> valuePairs=new HashMap<String,String>();

                    valuePairs.put("vehicle_id",c.getString(TAG_id));
                    valuePairs.put("vehicle_no", c.getString(TAG_no));
                    String state1 = c.getString(TAG_id);
                    String state2 = c.getString(TAG_no);
                    Log.d("states",state1 + state2);
                    state_cons.add(valuePairs);
                    state_cons.addAll(state_cons);

                    shippingid=state1;
                    cids=state2;

                    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

                    adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);

                    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

                // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
                dialog.show();

            }catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        });}}
```

ListViewAdapter class:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;

HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
    this.context = context;
    data = arraylist;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();

}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    TextView vehicle_id;
    TextView vehicle_no;

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
    }

    /*inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);*/

    /*View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);*/

    resultp = data.get(position);

    vehicle_id = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.vid);
    Log.d("vehicle_id", "name" + vehicle_id);
    vehicle_no = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.vno);
    Log.d("vehicle_no", "name" + vehicle_no);

    vehicle_id.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.TAG_id));
    vehicle_no.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.TAG_no));

    v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            resultp = data.get(position);

            /*
             * intent.putExtra("name", resultp.get(Update.NAME));
             * intent.putExtra("age", resultp.get(Update.AGE));
             * 
             * 
             * context.startActivity(intent);
             */

        }

    });
    return v;
}}
```

THANK YOU.

Comment: What is line number 106 in `MainActivity.java`

Comment: listview.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: @DeathMetalRules post `activity_main.xml`

Answer (score 0):

```
adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
```

Need to assign "arrayList" , if that is declared as a variable, it is empty

Answer (score 0):

```
adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
```

I think arraylist value is Null.....

Answer (score 0):

I see you are probably running network related operation on the main thread which is not possible.

You should use a `Thread` or `AsyncTask` for this purpose.

This part must be in a background thread

```
json2=JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://192.168.1.63/inba/mtc/mtc_enduser/vehicle_id_pop.php");
```

If you say line 106 is `listview.setAdapter(adapter);` listview is null. Check if oyu have listview with id `listView1` in `activity_main.xml`

Comment: the `ListView` with id 'listview1' is not in `activity_main.xml` but in `custom.xml` present in class `MainActivity`

Comment: @DeathMetalRules then you can't initialize it in your `MainActivtiy.java` as `findViewById` looks for a view with the id in the current inflated layout. Hence the `NullPointerException`.